# Making elements disappear in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make multiple elements appear with the click of a button using one script.

This is supposed to happen: button b1 hides p1 and button b2 hides p2.

This is my current code:

```html
<html>
<body>

<p id="p1">Disapear 1</p>

<button id="b1" onclick="toggle(p1)">hide 1</button>

<p id="p2">Disapear 2</p>

<button id="b2" onclick="toggle(p2)">hide 2</button>

<script>
function toggle(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById("id");
  if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    x.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to carry information with the click of a button to the function.

Comment: Please add your HTML as well to see how the elements are related to this script ?

Comment: Use class to target your buttons and add a event handler for the class to do `contacttoggle`.

Comment: If you want multiple elements with same function , use class instead of id .

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*I am trying to do this with many buttons*"? Do you have different buttons to work on different element ids / HTML/ pages? Please explain what you are trying to do and show us an example of the HTML this code works on, so that we can help.

Comment: Provide your html code too

Comment: If you use class or data attribute, you can get those buttons using `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 0):

A clean, DRY solution would be to [avoid inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) and iterate over all `buttons` on the page. Add a click listener to each that navigates to the button's `previousElementSibling` to toggle a class that either hides or shows the `<p>`:

```js
for (const button of document.querySelectorAll('button')) {
  button.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
    target.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle('hidden');
  });
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p>Disapear 1</p>
<button>hide 1</button>

<p>Disapear 2</p>
<button>hide 2</button>
```

You can also use event delegation to attach just one listener to the parent, instead of a listener to each button:

```js
window.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.matches('button')) {
    target.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<p>Disapear 1</p>
<button>hide 1</button>

<p>Disapear 2</p>
<button>hide 2</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this function and call each button with its ID.

```
function contactToggle(ElementID) {
  x = document.getElementById(ElementID);
  if (x.style.visibility === "visible") {
    x.style.visibility = "hidden";
  } else {
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
```

For example you have buttons like:

```
<button id="hey">Click me</button>
<button id="hello">Click me</button>
```

In your javascript:

```
contactToggle(document.getElementById('hey'));
contactToggle(document.getElementById('hello'));
```

Comment: How do I reopen this question, I made it much more clear. Also it is my first time using this site.

Comment: @TylerBowers - Members of the community with sufficient reputation can vote on whether to re-open a question (e.g. after the OP has edited it, like you have). Read more about that process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions). You currently have 2 of the 3 needed "reopen" votes.